# Finding polyhedrons formed by a set of (possibly intersecting) triangles

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, intersection

Is there an established, efficient algorithm for finding the polyhedrons that can be formed by intersecting triangles in 3D space?

Specifically, I have one set of triangles that already form a polyhedron (say *M*), as well as a set of other unrelated triangles (say *T*). I am searching for polyhedrons that can be formed by the intersection of triangles from *M* and *T*, with at least one face formed by (part of) a triangle from *M*. Though I'm happy to approach the problem as it stands, I'm interested in whether or not there is an appropriate existing algorithm?

Comment: Are you looking for all possible polyhedrons from all combinations of M and T triangles or something more specific? Can we also replace triangles with planes, or triangle boundaries are important?

Comment: Triangle boundaries are important. I'm looking for polyhedrons that don't contain any smaller polyhedrons (can't be split by any collection of triangles from M or T). All possible such polyhedrons from all combinations of M and T are of interest.

Comment: First I thought about it as planes dividing space but with triangles I can't imagine what would be the correct result. Do you have any examples and/or pictures of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my latest lib Geometry3D by

```sh
pip install Geometry3D
```

An example is shown below

```py
>>> from Geometry3D import *
>>>
>>> a = Point(1,1,1)
>>> b = Point(-1,1,1)
>>> c = Point(-1,-1,1)
>>> d = Point(1,-1,1)
>>> e = Point(1,1,-1)
>>> f = Point(-1,1,-1)
>>> g = Point(-1,-1,-1)
>>> h = Point(1,-1,-1)
>>> cph0 = Parallelepiped(Point(-1,-1,-1),Vector(2,0,0),Vector(0,2,0),Vector(0,0,2))
>>> cpg12 = ConvexPolygon((e,c,h))
>>> cpg13 = ConvexPolygon((e,f,c))
>>> cpg14 = ConvexPolygon((c,f,g))
>>> cpg15 = ConvexPolygon((h,c,g))
>>> cpg16 = ConvexPolygon((h,g,f,e))
>>> cph1 = ConvexPolyhedron((cpg12,cpg13,cpg14,cpg15,cpg16))
>>> a1 = Point(1.5,1.5,1.5)
>>> b1 = Point(-0.5,1.5,1.5)
>>> c1 = Point(-0.5,-0.5,1.5)
>>> d1 = Point(1.5,-0.5,1.5)
>>> e1 = Point(1.5,1.5,-0.5)
>>> f1 = Point(-0.2,1.5,-0.5)
>>> g1 = Point(-0.2,-0.5,-0.5)
>>> h1 = Point(1.5,-0.5,-0.5)
>>>
>>> cpg6 = ConvexPolygon((a1,d1,h1,e1))
>>> cpg7 = ConvexPolygon((a1,e1,f1,b1))
>>> cpg8 = ConvexPolygon((c1,b1,f1,g1))
>>> cpg9 = ConvexPolygon((c1,g1,h1,d1))
>>> cpg10 = ConvexPolygon((a1,b1,c1,d1))
>>> cpg11 = ConvexPolygon((e1,h1,g1,f1))
>>> cph2 = ConvexPolyhedron((cpg6,cpg7,cpg8,cpg9,cpg10,cpg11))
>>> cph3 = intersection(cph0,cph2)
>>>
>>> cph4 = intersection(cph1,cph2)
>>> r = Renderer()
>>> r.add((cph0,'r',1),normal_length = 0)
>>> r.add((cph1,'r',1),normal_length = 0)
>>> r.add((cph2,'g',1),normal_length = 0)
>>> r.add((cph3,'b',3),normal_length = 0.5)
>>> r.add((cph4,'y',3),normal_length = 0.5)
>>> r.show()
```

[Result][1]

You can also look at the documentation [Geomrtry3D](https://github.com/GouMinghao/Geometry3D)

The algorithm is a little complex and may not be the best. But the library supports a log of geometries.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a3ko.png